# Exclude One Category and its Subcategories using WP_LIST_FILTER

Tags: filters, exclude

I need to exclude a category and its subcategories in posts.
This is the code I'm working on and it works:

```
        <?php
        $categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category');
        $categories = wp_list_filter($categories, array('slug'=>'regione'), 'NOT');
        $categories = wp_list_filter($categories, array('slug'=>'lazio'), 'NOT');
        $categories = wp_list_filter($categories, array('slug'=>'rm'), 'NOT');
        if (!empty($categories)) {
            ?>
            <ul class="category">
                <?php
                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $cat = get_category($category);
                    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link($category) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></li>';
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
```

Although, the category 'regione' has more than 20 subcats and each subcat has 5 to 10 other subcats: any suggestion on how to exclude in a better way the main category and its children?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering a question after like 6 months, so I expect the quality of my answer not upto WPSE standards and hence would love feedback from other experience WPSE gurus.

Add the following function to your functions.php

```
function filter_category_list_by_slug( $slug, $categories ) {
    $excluded_parent = get_category_by_slug( $slug );
    $excluded_cats = get_categories( array( 'child_of' => $excluded_parent->term_id ) );
    $excluded_cats[] = $excluded_parent;
    $filtered = array();
    $matched = false;
    foreach ($categories as $category ) {
        $matched = false;
        foreach( $excluded_cats as $ex_cat ) {
            if ( $category->term_id == $ex_cat->term_id ) {
                $matched = true;
            }
        }
        if ( ! $matched ) {
            $filtered[] = $category;
        }
    }
    return $filtered;
}
```

And the filter the category list like following:

```
$categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category');
$categories = filter_category_list_by_slug( 'regione', $categories );
$categories = filter_category_list_by_slug( 'lazio', $categories );
$categories = filter_category_list_by_slug( 'rm', $categories );
```

Comment: Ciao Hameedullah, I tried out your code but the post doesn't output any category. Could you check it out again? Grazie, diana

Comment: I worked it out! Had to change 'parent1' to my cat named 'regione' in the functions.php file and all is perfect! Thank you so much, very good indeed! Grazie again, diana

Comment: sorry diana it was a typo, I fixed the code. it was using the hardcoded parent1 category instead of the one being passed to the funciton.